# How can I create a method to /2 the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

I am learning to code and I am trying out this javascript object method course. I am currently stuck on this method. I want to have the array with three different numbers(2,5,10) to be /2. I do not understand why it is returning NaN. Thank you for reading.

```
//Eggs hatch time
eggHatchTime2km = 2
eggHatchTime5km = 5
eggHatchTime10km = 10

allEggsTime = [eggHatchTime2km,eggHatchTime5km,eggHatchTime10km];
console.log(allEggsTime); //reads out 2,5,10

const pokemonGoCommunityDay = {
  eventBonuses: {
    calculateEggHatchTime() {
      return allEggsTime/2; //return NaN
      //return eggHatchTime2km,eggHatchTime5km,eggHatchTime10km/2; //return the value of the last variable(10km) but not 2km and 5km

    },
  }
}

console.log(pokemonGoCommunityDay);
console.log(pokemonGoCommunityDay.eventBonuses.calculateEggHatchTime());
```

Comment: You're trying to use `/` on an array, but `/` only makes sense with numbers. You need to loop through each item in `allEggsTime` and divide those, then push the result into a new array (or update the item at the current index to hold the new calculated value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using .map()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
const pokemonGoCommunityDay = {
    eventBonuses: {
        calculateEggHatchTime() {
            const halfEggsTime = allEggsTime.map(egg=>egg/2)
            return halfEggsTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try .forEach to apply the same function to each element in an array

```
const pokemonGoCommunityDay = {
    eventBonuses: {
        calculateEggHatchTime() {
            const halfEggsTime = allEggsTime.forEach(egg=>egg/2)
            return halfEggsTime;
        }
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: This return undefined. I'm not sure why

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't returnn anything (it returns `undefined`). You need to use `.map()` instead to return a new array

Comment: Sorry, try this instead.
const eggHatchTime2km = 2
const eggHatchTime5km = 5
const eggHatchTime10km = 10

allEggsTime = [eggHatchTime2km,eggHatchTime5km,eggHatchTime10km];
console.log(allEggsTime);

const pokemonGoCommunityDay = {
    eventBonuses: {
        calculateEggHatchTime() {
            let halfEggsTime = []
            allEggsTime.forEach((egg,index) => {halfEggsTime[index] = egg/2})
            return halfEggsTime;
        }
    }
}

console.log(pokemonGoCommunityDay);
console.log(pokemonGoCommunityDay.eventBonuses.calculateEggHatchTime())